# How to show multiple View Controllers inside a View Controller in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I need to implement one functionality that I have one screen that contains header and footer. And then the middle area of the screen is dynamic. I want to change the middle area as per requirement but I do not know what should I do as I am new to iOS. Please, tell me what functionality I can use.

Please check below screenshot for my requirement :

[image: requirement]

Comment: Use a **container view**. It's in the object library in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use container view controller for this purpose, Container views allow a view to have child views which are in turn managed by their own view controllers. The UINavigationController and UITabBarController are examples of container view controllers.

> The only requirement from UIKit is that you establish a formal
>   parent-child relationship between the container view controller and
>   any child view controllers.

You can use storyboard or do it in code like below

```
private func addChildViewController() {

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildViewController") as! ChildViewController

// Add Child View Controller
addChildViewController(viewController)

// Add Child View as Subview
view.addSubview(viewController.view)

// Configure Child View
viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

// Notify Child View Controller
viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

this is [tutorial](https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/) link